# MultiAutoCompleteTextView with dynamic adapter changes

Tags: android, backgroundworker, autocompletetextview

I have a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` widget in my Activity, which has an `ArrayAdapter<String>` that is populated by a result from a web-based call. As the user types in characters in the textview, this adapter's list should get updated in the background. What is the best way to implement this?

I have already tried to use `AsyncTask` to download the strings list in the background, but `notifyDataSetChanged()` was being called from the "non-originating thread". Moreover, this seems a little roundabout.

The other option I came across is that `Filterable` can be used, but I haven't come across any simple examples ([AutoComplete4](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/AutoComplete4.html) seems like an overkill) on how to do this. If there are no examples, can someone give a broad overview of the actors i will need - Filter, Filterable, etc.

Also is this a good way to go?

Thanks,
Rajath

Comment: Have you got any solution

Comment: @user1767260, it's been more than two years that I had posted this questions; I don't think I pursued this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had to do the same thing and I figured I'd share the solution with you or anybody would need it.

First of all, you will indeed need to use an `AsyncTask` to retrieve your data. This being said, I'd never let an AsyncTask manipulate in any way my view class. Instead, I'd rather use a **callback** passed along with the parameters you need in your AsyncTask. As soon as the AsyncTask finishes, you will call your callback method which will be responsible of calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Here's some code:

**MyAsyncTask.java**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    MyController callbackClass = (MyController) params[0];

    // Get your other parameters and do your stuff here...

    // Call the setter with the data you get back and refresh the view
    // either here or implementing onPostExecute.
    callbackClass.setMyData(myData);
    callbackClass.refreshView();

    // Return any object if you need.
    return null;
 }
}
```

**MyCallbackClass.java**

```
 public MyCallbackClass extends Fragment{

   private List<MyDataType> myData;

   private ArrayAdapter<MyDataType> myAdapter;

   // Your methods including setters and getters.

    public void refreshFriendList(){
     if(myAdapter == null){
      initAutoCompleteView();
     }
     myAdapter.clear();
     myAdapter.addAll(myData);
     myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

}
```